# Implementing Oauth2 and create JWT from access token in spring

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am implementing authentication in my application. Client side is in **Angular 2** and back end in **Spring** boot. Back end is just rest API server and both end is deployed at different server.

I am using Facebook as Authentication provider.

Below are the steps that I have done:

1. Registered my app with Facebook and got client id and secret key.
2. Using Facebook Javascript SDK at client side, user is authenticated and received access code.

Initially my understanding was that I will send access code in every request to server and server will validate access token with Facebook if it is still valid. This will make call to Facebook Authorization server on every request, So to avoid this we can create our JWT token from access token. Now next step would be:

3. Client will send access token to server and server will create JWT token from access token and return to client.
4. On every request client will send the JWT instead of access token and server can verify it.

First of all can somebody validate my understanding, I am bit confused. I am looking for what are the best practices here.

And I am not able to find:

a. Validating access token and get user information.

b. Create JWT from access token.

I saw lot of articles but they have added a lot of complexities of implementing Authorization server etc with full framework. I want to implement it manually without any framework.